# Cycle over list indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
x = a

def change_x():
    x = next??
    print("x:", x)

for i in range(10):
    change_x()
```

How can I cycle through a, b, c by calling change_x() indefinitely?

Output should be:

```
x: 2
x: 3
x: 1
x: 2
...
```

Comment: Are the variables a, b and c needed? Can you just cycle through a list? [1,2,3]

Comment: why does the output start from the value for `b` instead of `a`?

Comment: Most of the answer point you the right tool `itertools.cycle` but none actually answer your question. Define your `change_x()` function as the following: `def change_x(c=cycle([a, b, c])): return next(c)`

Comment: @Ashish: Yes the variables are needed they are acutely tk.StringVars in a GUI

Comment: @Sayse: It starts with b because print is after the first change

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and call `next()` as many times as you want to get cycled values.

```
from itertools import cycle

values = [1, 2, 3]
c = cycle(values)

for _ in range(10):
    print(next(c))
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
```

or as @chepner suggested without using `next()`:

```
from itertools import islice

for i in islice(c, 10):
    print(i)
```

To get the same result.

Comment: I like this solution because you take advantage of cycle as a generator and can get as few or many as you want

Comment: In fact, you don't even need to call `next` explicitly; `for i in islice(c, 10): print(i)`.

Comment: to match OP's requirements (*How can I cycle through a, b, c by calling change_x() indefinitely?*) you can make it a function: `def change_x(c=cycle([a, b, c])): return next(c)`

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), to cycle around the values in `a`, `b` and `c` as specified:

```
from itertools import cycle
for i in cycle([a,b,c]):
    print(f'x: {i}')
```

**Output**

```
x: 1
x: 2
x: 0
x: 1
x: 2
x: 0
x: 1
x: 2
x: 0
x: 1
...
```

Comment: @Yatu Having a infinite stream is useful for things like zipping with a sequence of finite but unknown length. It will give you "enough" in any case.

Comment: I was also thinking in the cases with multiple iterables, and some are finite. Wasn't so sure about a single iterable, but yes, that would indeed be one case where this could be useful. Thanks for pointing out @chepner

Answer (score 3):

this is what `itertools.cycle` does

```
import itertools,time

for i in itertools.cycle([1,2,3]):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put your variables in a list then pick them this way:

```
mylist = [a,b,c]
i=0
while True:
   print(mylist[i%3])
   i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the function by hand then you use `yield from`:

```py
def cycle(iterables):
    while True:
        yield from iterables
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have meant to use the global environment variables in this way but it is possible to follow what you're doing using an object.

This makes the assumption that you know the names of the variable so that you can use `globals()` to access the value of these.

```
class CycleThrough:
    def __init__(self, variable_list = ['a','b','c']):
        self.variable_list = variable_list
        self.current_variable_idx = 0
        self.total_length = len(self.variable_list)

    def next_variable(self):
        new_index = self.current_variable_idx + 1
        if new_index == self.total_length:
            new_index = 0 

        self.current_variable_idx = new_index

        variable_name = self.variable_list[self.current_variable_idx]


        global x 
        x = globals()[variable_name]
        print(x)

# defining your variables
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3 
x = a

#use object method to cycle through and reassign the global variable x

ct = CycleThrough()
for i in range(10):
    ct.next_variable()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alternative that does not use `itertools`, you can create a class that returns the list you want to cycle, then in the loop you can print the list as it is shown in the following code:

```
class Repeater:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return self.l

l = Repeater([1, 2, 3])

for e in l:
    print(*[f"x: {i}" for i in e], sep='\n')
```

I am assuming you are using Python 3.6+, otherwise, change the print statement to:

```
print(*["x: {}".format(i) for i in e], sep='\n')
```

### Output:

```
x: 1
x: 2
x: 3
x: 1
x: 2
x: 3
x: 1
x: 2
x: 3
x: 1
x: 2
x: 3
x: 1
```